# How can i move Apache localhost from /var/www to my mount directory

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, mount

I am new in ubuntu(and Linux) and have simple-lamer question.

I have mounted directory /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/ and would like to move http:/localhost/ from var/www to /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/

I have change sites-enabled/000-default and /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And have this apache message!

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server**

When i have created "test" dir and move localhost from var/www to var/www/test - everything works. I suppose that problem with file permissions??!What should i do?

---

The problem has been solved. Thanks Patrick and Joh. Really need to give read access to index.html: chmod 644 /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/index.html

But i can't change access to my Ntfs mounted drive. I have to remount

why cant change permission ownership group of external hard drive on ubuntu

Comment: Hi there, this would stand a better chance of a constructive answer on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

The apache server runs as a certain user -- probably "apache", you can run `ps` to see -- and that user must have permission to access the webroot. You can make it be owned by apache, or make it group-readable (and you'll probably want it group-writable) and either add apache to the group that owns it, or change the group to apache's group.

Assuming httpd runs as "apache" (group: apache) and you are "jdoe" (group: jdoe)

```
$ sudo chown -R jdoe:apache /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject
$ sudo chmod -R 755 /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject
```

Comment: One of those -R should be lowercase. I forget. I always just RTFM when I need to. I also forget the syntax for usermod. Personally, I'd set jdoe's default group to apache, to make things easier. `usermod -G apache jdoe` (I think. Could be -g and reverse group and user order. `man usermod`)

Comment: Putting jdoe in apache's group isn't going to help. The apache user is the one that's attempting to access /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject you also probably don't want to change everything to mode 755 (thus making all files executable), you only want to make sure group can read, so `chmod -R g+r /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject`

Comment: I run ps -ax  And see `6000 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`... I run ls -l in /var/www and see -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  185 2011-08-14 10:08 index.html => Apache run under root. Owner of /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject - me(stepchik). ls -l /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject `-rw------- 1 stepchik stepchik   185 2011-08-14 10:08 index.html` As i undestood i must run apache under stepchik or change owner of /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject to root? (about group is not clear. How can i determine group).  In ls -l var/www - i dont't view user group(just root)

Comment: You need to give read access to index.html: `chmod 644 /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/index.html`

Comment: Sorry. I am confused but i can't change read access. I run `chmod 644 /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/index.html`   and ` sudo chmod 644 /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/index.html`  and `sudo chmod 777 /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/index.html`... Do `ls -l` and view same `-rw------- 1 stepchik stepchik   185 2011-08-14 10:08 index.html`

Comment: I think i have found [http://superuser.com/questions/57092/cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu](cant-change-permission-ownership-group-of-external-hard-drive-on-ubuntu)

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thanks Patrick and Joh. Really i

    need to give read access to index.html: chmod 644 /media/2A98EDD2ACA90087/WebProject/index.html

But i can't change access to my Ntfs mounted drive. I have to remount

why cant change permission ownership group of external hard drive on ubuntu